# More arguments required when I run my python/pyspark function

Tags: function, pyspark

I have a function which I have defined as follows, you can see that it clearly requires 7 arguments;

```
def calc_z(w,S,var,a1,a2,yt1,yt2):

    mu = w*S
    sigma = mt.sqrt(var)
    z = np.random.normal(mu,sigma)
    u = [a1,a2,z]
    yt = [yt1,yt2,1]
    thetaset = np.random.rand(len(u))
    m = [i for i in range(len(u))]

    max_iter = 30

#Calculate E-step
    for i in range(max_iter):

        print 'Iteration:', i
        print 'z:', z
        print 'thetaset', thetaset

        devLz = eq6(var,w,S,z,yt,u,thetaset,m)
        dev2Lz2 = eq9(var,thetaset,u)

#Calculate M-Step
        z = z - (devLz / dev2Lz2)
        w = lambdaw * z

        for i in range(len(thetaset)):

            devLTheta = eq7(yt,u,thetaset,lambdatheta)
            dev2LTheta2 = eq10(thetaset,u,lambdatheta)            

            thetaset = thetaset - (devLTheta / dev2LTheta2)

    return z
```

I am using pyspark so I convert this to a udf

```
calc_z_udf = udf(calc_z,FloatType())
```

and then run it as follows (where I am clearly passing in 7 arguments - Or am I going mad!?);

```
data = data.withColumn('z', calc_z_udf(data['w'],data['Org_Depth_Diff_S'],data['var'],data['proximity_rank_a1'],data['cotravel_count_a2'],data['cotravel_yt1'],data['proximity_yt2']))
```

When I run this however I am getting an error which states:

```
TypeError: calc_z() takes exactly 7 arguments (6 given)
```

Could anyone help me with why this might be as it is clear that when I am running the function I am infact passing in 7 arguments and not 6 as the error states?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure its is the reason no need to send column objects you can just pass strings:

```
data = data.withColumn('z', calc_z_udf('w', 'Org_Depth_Diff_S','var', 'proximity_rank_a1', 'cotravel_count_a2', 'cotravel_yt1', 'proximity_yt2'))
```